# Can I check for the entity a guardian is aiming at?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to give guardians a special ability to pull players toward them with their beam, can I somehow check for this? So I simply want to check for any existing beam, from there on out I can figure things out myself if I need to.

Edit: since beams are apparently rendered client-side, I'll change my question to: can I check for the entity a guardian is aiming at?
*Thanks to @54D in the comments for telling me this.*

Comment: Afaik a Guardian beam is a polygon that's rendered completely client-side (similar to a Beacon light beam). Your best bet would be to check when a Guardian attacks (inflicts damage on) the player?

Comment: I may be able to do it with a scoreboard that checks when a player takes damage from a specific team, which would be guardians?
Edit: there doesn't seem to be a scoreboard that allows that either, only killedByTeam.<color>.

Comment: I'm not available to whip up a full solution but try the `HurtTime` nbt tag and throw it into an execute if (that addresses how to detect the user getting hurt, you should probably execute that command at the guardian and detect players at a radius)

Comment: The problem with that is if the player gets hurt by any other source of damage. I think I'm just gonna have to make it a pull aura rather than the beam pulling players. I'm using this in a datapack that gives every mob an "empowered" version and unique drops for an RPG-like game that offers more challenge and variety than minecraft on its own. So I think I'll just go for something simpler, for now at least.